# Why would you collect dependencies if you are going to sample them on production?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

Application Insights can collect Dependencies as a part of the log analytics and recently it is enabled by default. Of course, having information regarding dependencies is increadible when you try to improve performance, but how can one use it when the sampling is on and the rate of data is a lot more than sampling rate?

To give an example, MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling) is 5 in their example. Having it enabled on production, the sum(itemCount) for my requests is around 400 and for dependencies is around 5000-6000. Regradless of the price, I wanted to has as much information as possible, so I've tried increasing the limit and I hit the performance problem on around 600. So I had to prioritize my events, exceptions and requests over the dependencies, so there will be a limit of max 100 rows for max sampling dependencies which means each row in my sampling data will represent 50 dependencies and I am at performance limit. If I go for 10 rows limit for dependencies, each row will represent 500 items.

My question is, what would be the use of the data that is sampled with a rate of 1:500? What is the gain? How can this be even helpful?

Answer (score 3):

Sampling is done to reduce the cost of telemetry. (financial cost + performance cost)
Even with sampling, the built-in sampling takes care to retain or discard related events. i.e If a RequestTelemetry is retained by sampling, then all the DependencyTelemetry within the context of that request is retained. This will give you enough to perform closer investigation of Requests, and how Dependencies are contributing to overall performance of the request.

You may also want to take a closer look at all the dependencies collected, and filter some of them if you think they are not very useful. For example - some people may chose to drop all very fast dependencies.

Access to raw Request/Dependencies are most needed on failures - you may write a telemetryprocessor to retain all failed dependencies. This will mean you'll have more data to investigate failures, while still sampling the rest of the telemetry.